# Exit action did not exit the app instead of back to previous

Tags: java, android

```
 public void onBackPressed ()
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder=new AlertDialog.Builder(GambarRumah.this);

        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Confirm Exit..!!");
        alertDialogBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_exit_to_app_black_24dp);
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?");
        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeText(GambarRumah.this, "You clicked on cancel buddy", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alertDialog=alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

    }
```

Comment: I need it to exit the application when i pressed the "yes" button, but if i pressed "yes" it will back to the previous page. if i pressed the "no" button, it will showed the text. but the "yes" button had the problem. please do help me.

Comment: i posted a code, it permits to get out

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about what's on-topic in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular, please include any explanation in your question description; don't use a comment for that.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to exit in the app when user click on exit, you only do the next

[image]

code

```
packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)?.let {
    android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
            .addNextIntentWithParentStack(it)
            .startActivities()
}
finishAndRemoveTask()
```

Comment: where to put this sir? on the same java file ?

Comment: you are welcome @Arif Zain. if you have any problem,  you write me please

Comment: Please don't post code (or other textual content) as an image. The content of an image cannot be searched. Always post code as formatted text.

Comment: Also, if this answer lead to you fixing your problem, standard practice is accepting it as the answer that helped you. That way the thread is no longer active and future people who might have a similar issue can profit from this thread as well.